# Determine whether it is a subspace of a vector space $P_3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Is the following a subspace of $P_3$?

$W=\left\{p(x)\in P_3 : a+b=c+d\right\}$

where $P_3$ is the vector space containing all the polynomials of the form $p(x)=ax^3 +bx^2 +cx+d$, $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}$.

I have done the following:

Choose $p_1(x),p_2(x)\in W$, such that $a_1+b_1=c_1+d_1$ (1) and $a_2+b_2=c_2+d_2$ (2). Then,

$p_1(x)+p_2(x)=a_1x^3 +b_1x^2 +c_1x+d_1 +a_2x^3 +b_2x^2 +c_2x+d_2=(a_1+a_2)x^3+(b_1+b_2)x^2+(c_1+c_2)x+(d_1+d_2)$

so $p_1(x)+p_2(x)\in W$ since it clearly satisfies the condition, if we add together the conditions (1) and (2).

Choose $p(x)\in W$ such that $a+b=c+d$ (3), and a scalar $\lambda$. Then,

$\lambda p(x)= \lambda ax^3 +\lambda bx^2 +\lambda cx+\lambda d$,

so $\lambda p(x)\in W$ since it clearly satisfies the condition, if we multiply condition (3) by $\lambda$.

Now, I am not sure whether the zero polynomial belongs to $W$. Is it true that choosing coefficients $a=b=c=d=0$ for the zero polynomial then the condition in $W$ is satisfied (0+0=0+0), so we can conclude that the zero polynomial belongs to $W$ and hence it is a subspace of $P_3$?

Comment: *Most certainly* . :) . $p(x) = 0 = 0x^3 + 0x^2 + 0x + 0$ is most definitely in $P_3$ . However, you only need to show $W$ is closed under addition and scalar multiplication. No need to verify it contains the zero vector, as this will automatically follow from the above mentioned :)

Comment: You have done enough by showing it is closed under addition and scalar multiplication.

Comment: Isn't a necessary condition that the zero polynomial must be an element of $W$?

Comment: @DJS thank you! Τhis gives an answer to my query!

Comment: @P.D. No problem! Closed under scalar multiplication confirms that it contains a zero vector. Simply choose $\lambda = 0$ and we have our zero vector :) Therefore containing zero vector is trivial and doesn't need to be verified in order to have a subspace

Comment: You certainly need to have the zero vector in any vector space, but when examining whether a subset of a vector space is a subspace, the zero vector comes automatically from scalar multiplication as the others have pointed out.